# Help with foreach, getting 'possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-6.0

Trying to do a foreach:

```
foreach(User in userList)
{

}
```

Where userList is a `IEnumerable<User> userList`

I tried doing:  userList.ToList() but I get the same message.

Comment: Is this Resharper related? Are you using userList at other places inside the same method?

Comment: yes it was resharper, thought it was a compilation issue!

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `foreach` statement, you haven't specified an identifier for the current instance of `User`. Try adding an identifier (e.g., `currUser` or just `user`) after the type `User`, like this:

```
foreach(User user in userList)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

the other answers showed you your syntax problem, but some tool (I think resharper) will warn you that you might enumerate the sequence more than once (maybe even VS - don't know because I use them together).
If that is the problem write something like

```
var userArray = userList.ToArray();
```

and use userArray instead of userList

Comment: see R# documentation: [link](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable)

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
foreach(User user in userList)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A foreach loop requires you to define a variable to place each iteration in.  You have only defined the class and are missing the variable.

```
foreach(User _user in userList)
{

}
```